# How to list files in directory in a non-blocking manner in Java?

Tags: java, file, nonblocking

Listing "files" in a directory is simple in Java using [Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) from the `nio` package:

```java
Stream<Path> paths = Files.list(Path.of("<folder>"))
```

However the call to `Files.list(..)` is blocking. How can I list the files in a directory in a non-blocking manner?

**Update**

By "blocking" I mean not blocking *any* thread as in the context of Reactive Programming. In my case I'm using [project reactor](https://projectreactor.io/) from [Spring](https://spring.io/) and I have a method defined like this:

```java
public Flux<String> doStuffWithFilesInDirectory(String dir) {
    // Intellij complains that the call to "Files.list(..)" is inappropriate since it's a blocking call
    var fileStream = Files.list(Path.of(dir)); 
    return Flux.fromStream(fileStream). ..
}
```

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "blocking" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is in the nature of disks that they don't yield information instantly. Therefore the possible "non-blocking" solutions are

(a) synchronous blocking execution in a separate thread, or

(b) initiation of an asynchronous operation with some notification mechanism (callback, Future, etc.) to tell you when it's done.

In the latter case, not only do you need this to be possible through some Java method, but the underlying OS needs to provide support. Since not all systems provide "asynchronous readdir", I suspect you won't find a Java interface either. This is an argument from general reasoning, so it's possible I'm wrong - but I wouldn't bet on it.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to run `Files.list` asynchronously from the invoking thread, you can do so without looking for "alternative" file APIs.

The most basic example would be:

```
Runnable lister = () -> {
    try {
        SomeReceivingClassOrInstance
            .someEventMethod(Files.list(Path.of("yourPath")));
    }
    catch (IOException ioe) {
        // TODO handle
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
};
```

You can then:

- Implement a method taking the a `Stream<Path>` on the receiver end, and acting upon.
- Invoke your `Runnable` asynchronously with `new Thread(lister).start();` from where you wish to start the operation asynchronously

Note that there are plenty alternative and more elegant/higher level examples around, to run operations asynchronously.

This is just a case to demonstrate that you *don't* really need to look further in the nio APIs (e.g. with `FileVisitor` etc. ) to asynchronize this.

**Note**

On after thought: if instead, you really wanted a colletion to lazily populate based on what the listing progressively "discovers", then you'd probably be better off starting a `FileVisitor` in its own thread, and populating a thread-safe colletion for every entry.

Comment: Thanks Mena, but the call to Files.list(..) in your example is still a blocking call, it's just blocked in another thread.

Comment: @Johan true. I've added a draft of an alternative in case your requirement is to lazily populate a collection rather than getting the whole of the result in bulk. If that is not the case, I don't think I understand your requirement - maybe add some context?

Comment: @Johan: Unless you can find a native non-blocking API to list files dedicating an extra thread to absorb the blocking is the only thing you can do. And that is a good solution, no?

Comment: @Thilo I'm sure it's a good solution, but imho it doesn't quite answer the question. Your comment might answer it though, maybe it's not supported? I'll try to update the question to make it a bit clearer.

Comment: @Johan unfortunately I've never had a chance to use project reactor, so I can't answer you in the specifics. However, if as I assume, a `Flux` provider is supposed to avoid any potentially long blocking invocation in its implementation, you could always "prepare" the listing and store it separately in a thread-safe collection - the `Flux` provider would just read from it, while the collection is periodically updated (or not) behind the scenes.

Comment: It is in the nature of disks that they don't yield information instantly. Therefore the possible "non-blocking" solutions are (a) synchronous blocking execution in a separate thread, or (b) initiation of an asynchronous operation with some notification mechanism (callback, Future, etc.) to tell you when it's done.  In the latter case, not only do you need this to be possible through some Java method, but the underlying OS needs to provide support.  Since not all systems provide "asynchronous readdir", I suspect you won't find a Java interface either.

Comment: @another-dave This would probably be the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: OK, I'll promote it.